# My local git shows differences between the files, but github doesn't

Tags: git, github

I've got a branch with two commits, one after the other, as shown by git log.

```
commit caa2cf6cf826398e64fbaa8d2972ebb6f7218f85
Author: Piers Beckley 
Date:   Fri Jun 3 14:55:18 2016 +0100

    Outputs a featured article in every 5th position

commit e1a3ea7b872eed153a29d24380916b69e675082d
Author: Co-Worker X
Date:   Fri Jun 3 14:41:46 2016 +0100

    share article on mobile
```

I check the files with git diff; 20 changed files, plenty of changes.

```
$ git diff --shortstat e1a3e caa2c
20 files changed, 987 insertions(+), 522 deletions(-)
```

But when I look at the second commit on github, it shows only one changed file.

```
commit caa2cf6cf826398e64fbaa8d2972ebb6f7218f85
Showing  1 changed file  with 31 additions and 18 deletions.
```

However, when I look at the specific files in the commit on github, I can see that the changes have, in fact happened - but they're not recorded as having happened there.

Does anyone know why this might be?

EDIT:

diffing the second commit with its parent (rather than the commit behind it in the branch) shows the same changes as on github - so I guess the question now becomes "How did the *other* changes happen between these two commits without being recorded?"

```
$ git diff --shortstat caa2c^ caa2c
1 file changed, 31 insertions(+), 18 deletions(-)
```

Comment: Is the GitHub repository public? If so, could you post links to the relevant commits?

Comment: Alas, it's a private repo so I can't share.

Comment: The git diff is done on the local branch, while the commit caa2... on the github repo?

Comment: These 2 commits might not be parent and child, but from different 2 branches which are merged together. Run `git log --graph` to see the commit graph.